# How to calculate these limits?

Tags: real-analysis

How to calculate

1) $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac {n!}{n^{n}}=0$,

2) $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\sqrt [n] {n}$,

3) $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\sqrt [n] {\dfrac {1}{n}}$?

Comment: You may want to ask these questions in different questions instead of squeezing them into the same question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) $$n!=1\cdot \underbrace{2}_{\leq n}\cdot ...\cdot \underbrace{n}_{\leq n}\leq n^{n-1}$$
and thus $$0\leq \frac{n!}{n^n}\leq \frac{1}{n}\underset{n\to \infty }{\longrightarrow } 0$$

2) $\sqrt[n]n=e^{\frac{\ln(n)}{n}}.$
Use the fact that $x\mapsto e^x$ is continous at $x=0$ and the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty }\frac{\ln(n)}{n}=0$.

3) use 2).